# Fetch all youtube videos from a channel React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use react-youtube in my React App and I want to retrieve all videos from a youtube channel. The case is that it must always show all videos as thumbnails referring the videos in YouTube, the same as they are listed in the channel in YouTube.

Can you please provide me a solution of how to do it. I've read the documentation and dozens of threads, but still can't find a solution.

My code for the page looks like this.

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Row, Col, ListGroup, Container, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';

const Media = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="landing-section landing-bg-gradiant">     
    
    </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Media;
```

I will really appreciate your help. I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display all the videos from a Youtube channel, you must use the Youtube API maintained by Google (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3).
The NPM package you showed us is to display a specific Youtube video in a React Component.

Comment: Can you provide me a solution of how to do it?

Comment: you have this youtube video which can help you to do what you want : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6t3bW7kx6E&ab_channel=HiteshChoudhary